# Why is pyqtgraph not rendering entire window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqtgraph

For some reason after installing `pyqtgraph` with `pip`, `GLScatterPlotItem` is only working in 1/4th of the screen.

The following hello world example code (given below) renders only in the bottom-left quadrant of the window:

[image]

The example above is given [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwigi6HQ18PdAhXChOAKHTkTAREQFjAAegQIABAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pyqtgraph.org%2Fdownloads%2F0.10.0%2Fpyqtgraph-0.10.0-deb%2Fpyqtgraph-0.10.0%2Fexamples%2FGLScatterPlotItem.py&usg=AOvVaw0hMk1zSFIheEuFemOlVqiP).  There must be some simple fix!?

**My environment:**

- MacOS High Sierra
- Python 3.6

Comment: I've tried the code and I have not had any problems: https://imgur.com/a/FBjrphq

Comment: You could show the code that you use in your question directly instead of a link that can be broken making your question unusable for future readers.